# Unable to use a Child Component inside Parent Component template in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Although I have added `FavoriteComponent` in `declarations[]` array in app.module.ts I am still getting the error:

> Unexpected directive 'FavoriteComponent' imported by the module
>   'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

**favorite.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  template: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>'  
})
export class FavoriteComponent   {    

}
```

**courses.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, transition } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'courses',
  templateUrl:  './courses.component.html'
  ,
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css'],

})
export class CoursesComponent  {
  text= `
    Lorem Ipsum is sumply a dummy text   Lorem Ipsum is sumply a dummy text 
  `
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import{FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { SummaryPipe } from './summary.pipe';
import { FavoriteComponent } from './favorite/favorite.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    SummaryPipe,
    FavoriteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule
  ],
  exports: [

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is-it possible to have your courses HTML ?

Comment: error looks like you may have accidentally put FavoriteComponent in your 'imports' array.

Comment: @derelict But I haven't